# Why does Gradle not always honour constraint requests?

Tags: java, gradle

When working with Gradle projects I find that it doesn't always honour declared constraints. A simple example would be `spring-boot-starter-tomcat:3.1.3` pulls in `tomcat-embed-core` but the version that it requires is 10.1.12 which currently has the CVE 2023-41080 open. Normally I should be able to place a constraint for 10.1.13 which does not currently have any open CVEs.

The problem is that Gradle does not always honour this request. With the simple example of:

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:3.1.3')
    constraints {
        // Bumping the version of Tomcat embedded as there are CVEs on 10.1.12
        implementation('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:10.1.13') {
            because '...'
        }
        implementation('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:10.1.13') {
            because '...'
        }
        implementation('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:10.1.13') {
            because '...'
        }
    }
}
```

My dependency tree resolves as so:

```
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:3.1.3
|    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:2.1.1
|    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:10.1.12
|    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:10.1.12
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:10.1.12
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:10.1.12
+--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:10.1.13 -> 10.1.12 (c)
+--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:10.1.13 -> 10.1.12 (c)
\--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:10.1.13 -> 10.1.12 (c)
```

Gradle documentation tells me:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html

> Often developers incorrectly fix transitive dependency issues by adding direct dependencies. To avoid this, Gradle provides the concept of dependency constraints.

But its the only way to get Tomcat to upgrade the version. What am I misunderstanding when adding dependency constraints, and why does Gradle not honour these configurations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override such constraints for example by using `force` in the `resolutionStrategy`.

If you use the Spring Dependency Management plugin which I assume from what I see, this does exactly that.
It has ways to override versions using properties that you should use instead if you really insist on using that plugin.

But actually, you should stop using that plugin. It is a relict from times where Gradle did not have built-in BOM support and nowadays does more harm than good. Even the maintainer of that plugin recommends not to use it anymore. So I strongly suggest you remove that plugin and instead use the built-in BOM support using `platform(...)`, then your constraint should also be taken into account accordingly.

For more information, have a look at [the Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#managing-dependencies.gradle-bom-support), [the Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:bom_import), and [the statement of the plugin maintainer](https://www.linen.dev/s/gradle-community/t/2579116/what-is-the-proper-way-to-apply-a-bom-in-a-library-project-i#a7d4a60a-ab60-48dc-8477-f3f4462d1e6a).